# Translation from blaze query to GraphQL query

Tags: jupyter-notebook, graphql, blaze

I have a data consumer which is a Jupyter Notebook. Is there any way to translate queries written in blaze to graphQL queries?

for example in blaze we have:

```
accounts[accounts.balance < 0].name
```

and in GraphQL we might have this:

```
{
accounts(balance<0)
{
name
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't expose any built-in filtering capability. It can be implemented manually in form of the parameters. So depending on your needs you may define query field like:

```
type Query {
    accounts(balanceBelow: Int!): [Account!]
}
```

or:

```
type Constraint {
    fieldName: String!
    operator: OperatorEnum!
    value: String!
}
type Query {
    accounts(where: Constraint): [Account!]
}
```

or something in between. But if things like custom query filtering and aggregations are common in your domain, you may find GraphQL cumbersome choice to work with.